# Interview FAIL: And I thought Google was tough

Tags: c#, .net, byte, bit

Okay, I've been on some hard interviews, but this was ridiculous. I was asked one question, given a pen, paper, calculator, definition of "URL-safe" characters, and 20 minutes to complete the question. The question was (as best I can remember):

> Write a function to generate a unique URL-safe string that represents a given
>   point in time for a file modification on an IIS web server that we're deploying
>   tomorrow. The resolution of a "point in time" is one second.
>
> .NET RegEx pattern for "URL-safe" characters = `[0-9a-zA-Z\$\-\_\.\+\!\*\'\(\)]`

I panicked and just wrote out my thinking instead of writing actual code. They dismissed me after viewing my "answer" because I didn't actually write any code. :(

What I wrote was something like:

> ```
> - 365 days in a year so "day of year" can be represented in 2 bytes
> - 4 digits in year (0 - 9999) so year can be represented in 3 bytes
> - 2 digits in hour (0 - 23) so year can be represented in 1 byte
> - 2 digits in minutes (0 - 59) so minutes can be represented in 1 byte
> - 2 digits in seconds (0 - 50) so seconds can be represented in 1 byte
>
> TOTAL: 2+3+1+1+1 = 8 bytes total that use 0 - 255 
>
> - URL-safe range == 10 + 24 + 24 + 10 == 0-9 + a-z + A-Z + special chars == 68
> - 4 bits required to represent URL safe char    
>
> ANSWER:
>
> - A byte is 8 bits
> - Only 4 bits per byte needed to represented the 8 bytes in a date
> - 8 / 2 = 4 
>
> FINAL ANSWER:
> - Only 4 actual bytes needed to represent hash
> ```

In other words, the timestamp hash could reasonably be represented in 4 URL-safe characters at most.

How would you have answered this?! I feel like I'm a pretty good developer but it's been many years since I've had to worry about calculating powers of two!

Comment: where does it say they were looking for the *minimum length* URL-safe string? Whas that indeed the task?

Comment: Well, rather than represent time as a string then hash, why not represent the number of seconds from midnight tonight?  You can implement it quickly with the Date and Timespan classes.

Comment: Think bits, not bytes.  And base72 encoding.

Comment: I would have answered a question that begins with "write a function" by *writing a function*. You were asked to write a function; you decided all on your own to instead answer the question "determine the minimum byte length of the string required and provide an argument supporting your conclusion". I would immediately no-hire someone who in an interview decided to answer a completely different question than the one I'd asked!

Comment: And even if the question were what you thought it to be, you have several mistakes in your calculation. | The alphabet has 26 letters, not 24. | 68 chars need 6.1 bits, not 4 | And everything after "ANSWER" makes no sense what so ever.

Comment: I think that you'll find that the point of this interview question was to test your understanding of regex **and** your ability to come up with a quick and simple answer (the latter you failed terribly at). That the question said "we're deploying tomorrow" implies that they want a simple answer that can be sure to work 100% of the time. I think any interviewer would promptly dismiss after seeing this answer. You clearly panicked and were out to impress your complex thought process but all they wanted was a single line of code.

Answer (score 5):

This seems almost like a FizzBuzz problem... based on requirements

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
```

or something very similar to it is a good answer and as an interviewer I would be highly skeptical of anyone who didn't write any code because they chose to make the problem needlessly complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I misunderstand the intent of the question, but

```
var timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss"); // or whatever DateTime source
```

should be unique and "URL-safe", no?

Comment: should really be UtcNow since it is possible for your code to generate the same value for multiple times with time zones and DST.

Comment: Yes, you are right. On the other hand: The source of the time stamps are file modification times in the example (and not .Now/.UtcNow), so I would expect them to be in UTC anyhow.